# Setting the ToolTip in a WPF chart?

Tags: wpf

I would like to set the ToolTip on my chart line, pie, area, bubble to include both the X and the Y values.

Charting is use is defined here :
xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"

I've learned that I can use the ControlTemplate to do this and by overriding the entire thing, I can also set the tooltip.
But this also changes things which I like, the random color selection, the status changes etc.

Is there a way to apply only the tooltip binding to all chart series types, without having to override the entire thing for each of the types (that makes for a very long and mostly irrelevant code, which mostly I don't understand and don't care about)

Thanks! (My first post)

...

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question because I don't know what chart control you are using.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?? @JudahHimango: He is/we are using WPF Toolkit

Answer (score 1):

You *have* to copy a part of the original source (the style).

Check this site: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/22/nobody-likes-a-show-off-today-s-datavisualizationdemos-release-includes-new-demos-showing-off-stacked-series-behavior.aspx

Here you can download **[this](http://dlaa.me/Samples/DataVisualizationDemos/DataVisualizationDemos.zip)** zip file that contains an example project in WPF.

Read the source/style in `ChartStyling.xaml` and your question will most likely be answered!